# angularjs json header request

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, post

if I do this I can get a data .. 
but, it's not json..

```
     var url = 'inputtest.php';
     $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: url,
         data: $.param($scope.company),
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        }).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
```

so, if I change like this

```
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
```

I don't get any parameter from it.

===> headers info says "Request Payload" ?? instead of Request Data

server side. just testing it.

```
          echo json_encode($_REQUEST);
```

I don't know what's wrong and how to fix it.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

i think it's not a javascript problem but more a server side issue.

You should try to add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before your echo in your php file

Answer (score 1):

put both in header..

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;application/json'}
```